# How to add a custom jquery file for custom shipping additional file in magento 2

Tags: custom, shipping-methods, jquery, magento2.2.2, additional-information

I have created a custom shipping method + shipping form like below.

[image]

I want to add click event for the check box.

I tried this code in my phtml file.

```
<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {

        $("#chk_shipusgovt").click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                alert("Checked");
                document.getElementById("txt_shipusgovt").style.display = "block";
            }

            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                alert("Not Checked");
                document.getElementById("txt_shipusgovt").style.display = "none";
            }
        });   
    }
);
```

This is not working, how can i add this JQuery function to be work.Great help if any one can help me to short it out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for click event.

```
$(document).on("click", '#chk_shipusgovt', function(event) { 
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```